# A user posted a blatantly OT answer to my question

Tags: discussion

A new user came here and trolled in [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36296315/1105249). I flagged the question for moderation attention. This never happened to me. Is it ok to downvote? Or should I flag? (BTW I did both).

How do more experienced SE users handle these situations?

Comment: Flag as "not an answer". That will cause it to be reviewed and eventually removed.

Comment: Yes, this is very common on SO. When you'll reach 10K, please visit the NATO queue- you won't believe your eyes.

Comment: It's gone now ...

Comment: Regarding on how to handle it- flag for sure. Downvote is also good. Leaving an automatic comment could removing it faster (if the OP actually won't ignore it). If you over 20K- some say delete- others will say save your delete votes for more important instances and let the mods delete this one. I personally, vote to delete it so it will also enter the delete votes queue and possibly get deleted faster. But I guess it's up to you to decide (when you'll reach 20K).

Comment: *Does this happen frequently?* is a horrific question title, even here in Meta. How will that possibly be of any use to future readers in a search result?

Comment: I second @KenWhite's comment -- please improve the title of this question so that it reflects and summarizes the question contents; otherwise it will be completely useless for future visitors.

Comment: "Trolling"? I would not call single instance that way... There are plenty of other words that can describe such behavior (some are even acceptable on SO), but trolling does not sound like a good word choice.

Comment: Updated the title. However, I'm still not sure whether it reflects the spirit of the facts.

Comment: What appropriate word could I use instead of trolling? Cant find a good choice in english, spanish, or even quichua XDDD.

Comment: @DavidArenburg What does NATO stand for in this context? Just curious.

Comment: @HappyCoder New Answers To Old questions.

Answer (score 7):

Users post answers which do not answer the question frequently. They would do this with comments too if there was not a 50 reputation barrier.

Answers are easier to community moderate than comments so that is partially why there are less barriers to posting these as answers versus comments. There are plenty of other reasons but that is getting off topic.

Downvoting and flagging was the best response here. In addition, you can add a *constructive* comment explaining some reasons for the downvote or flag with regards to Stack Overflow conventions. However, your comment

> Sounds like a trolling. Not even a comment.

Isn't very constructive. While I understand your concern here, it is best to avoid combative comments like this in these situations. In the future, try to strike a more neutral tone.

Comment: Yes u're right. Just did not know how to react. The answer was like the user was out-of-self. Usually I downvote, comment, wait fix, and de-downvote but this one almost shocked me.

Comment: I would say it's generally best to not reply to trolls at all, if you believe someone is just trolling. It only encourages them.

Comment: @LuisMasuelli - Welcome to the club I suppose :) I have seen far worse than that. Profanity, threats, pure just vulgarity. At least this one had some direction related to question asking (who,what,where).